# SQL Server merge replication with Web Synchronization

Tags: sql-server, iis, replication

I have a virtual machine in the cloud that runs SQL Server and a database that is publishing for merge replication. I have followed all the steps as outlined in Microsoft documentation but my subscriber client is getting stuck with the following error...

***The remote server 'xxxx.cloudapp.net' does not exist, or has not been designated as a valid Publisher, or you may not have permission to see available Publishers.***

The client has created the subscription and is able to connect to the server in order to get this far and so the server definitely does exist and can be communicated with. I have given full permission to access the ReplData directory for all users so I cannot see how permission would be a problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the account that is used to connect to the Publisher and Distributor, a member of the PAL, a login associated with a user in the publication database, and a login associated with a user in the distribution database?

Comment: Also, which ports do you have open on your virtual machine?

Comment: Ports 80, 443, 1433, and 3389.

Comment: Yes, I have added the local machine administrator to the PAL and it is also a login for the publisher and distributor databases.